# How to get the markers details in the drawn polygon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

The markers will be added dynamically using firebase.

```
map.loadImage(
AddressIcon,
function(error, image) {
    if (error) throw error;
    map.addImage(id + 'address', image);
    map.addSource(id + 'point', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [
                features
            ]
        }
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': id + "addresses-layer",
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': id + 'point',
        'layout': {
            'icon-image': id + 'address',
            'icon-size': 1
        }
    });
});

draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        userProperties: true,
        controls: {
            polygon: true,
            trash: true
        },
    });

map.addControl(draw, 'bottom-left');
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());

map.on('draw.create', updateDrawArea);
map.on('draw.delete', updateDrawArea);
map.on('draw.update', updateDrawArea);

const updateDrawArea = (e) => {
    var data = draw.getAll();
    console.log(data);
}
```

I have the polygon drawing system on the map. I need to get all of the added layers/markers after draw the polygon around the markers. I need to do this using mapbox-gl-js if possible. If not is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible through [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/).

Turf.js exposes functions such as `pointsWithinPolygon`, that allow us to specify `marker points` and `polygon` coordinates, and returns a list of markers that inside the specified polygon.

For example:

```
var pointsWithinPolygon = require("@turf/points-within-polygon")
const turf = require('@turf/turf');

var points = turf.points([
    [-46.6318, -23.5523],
    [-46.6246, -23.5325],
    [-46.6062, -23.5513],
    [-46.663, -23.554],
    [-46.643, -23.557]
]);

var searchWithin = turf.polygon([[
    [-46.653,-23.543],
    [-46.634,-23.5346],
    [-46.613,-23.543],
    [-46.614,-23.559],
    [-46.631,-23.567],
    [-46.653,-23.560],
    [-46.653,-23.543]
]]);

var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, searchWithin);
console.log(ptsWithin)
```

You can refer to [this](https://medium.com/@anujsingh_wd/custom-draw-on-map-mapbox-gl-js-mapbox-draw-gl-turf-js-react-js-af579bdaa05f) tutorial that explains how we can use turf.js along-side mapbox-gl-draw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I was not able to describe properly. I need all of the markers inside the drawn polygon. https://prnt.sc/t9g44p Please refer to this image I have updated your fiddle to describe you.

Comment: @TareqAziz I have updated my answer based on your clarification. I would recommend updating the question with this clarification so that the future visitors to this post get the correct information.